# Best place to start learning magento?

Tags: discussion

I am new to magento and I need to learn it really fast, because I need to work with it in a company where I just started to work.

I have access to test servers from our company's shops, but it is very confusing to me and I don't know where to start.

How would you recommend me to start learning magento?

I tried to create an account [here](https://u.magento.com/customer/account/create/), but I get `captcha is not valid` even though there is not even a captcha on their site. I need the account to watch free video tutorials though.

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same position as you were. Can you please tell what path did you took to learn and understand Magento.

Comment: @TajveezRehman, yes. I learned it by buying a good magento developer book and I was getting better from task to task. My company was giving me much time to learn and I had no stress. You can also get better by reading the questions here and try to understand the answers.

Comment: thanks, can you please suggest the book?

Comment: @TajveezRehman, It is a german book, so im not sure if it will help you: https://www.amazon.de/Online-Shops-mit-Magento-Roman-Zenner/dp/3955617823/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1551867927&sr=8-2&keywords=magento

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no single place to learn Magento. You need to depend on multiple sources.

However, the best one which I recommend is [AlanStorm's blog](https://alanstorm.com/).

Also, see the learning resources which are listed in the [following link](https://github.com/aleron75/mageres). These are good enough to start your fun.

There are also questions similar to this in the Magento Stack Exchange itself.

I feel this question won't fit on the meta site.

Comment: +1 for mentioning @alessandro-ronchi mageres, that's a brilliant place to start